# If Statement with Multiple Conditions vs Individual If Statements

Tags: c#

I would like to check each condition and `return` if true.

---

**Is it better to have:**

**1.** Multiple conditions in a single `if` statement?

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr) ||
    myBool == true ||
    myList.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}
```

**2.** Or multiple `if` statements, each checking a different condition.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myStr))
{
    return;
}

if (myBool == true)
{
    return;
}

if (myList.Count == 0)
{
    return;
}
```

---

If `myStr` is `Empty`.

My thought is that the first way checks all 3 conditions before it reaches the `return` (or does it)?

And the second way only has to check the 1st condition `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, reaches the `return`, and doesn't have to process the other 2 condition checks below it.

---

Or does the compiler optimize the code to work most efficient no matter how the source is written?

Comment: The operators `||` and `&&` do shortcuts if possible. So if for `x || y` `x` evaluates to `true` then `y` will not be evaluated.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev That is a different question. I'm asking the first example has to check all 3 conditions, or does it stop as soon as it reaches one that is true and then goes to the `return`, skipping the other condition checks?

Comment: @Ackdari I think that answers my question. So both examples 1 and 2 work the same, and don't evaluate the other conditions if one before it is `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are equivalent. The `||` operator short-circuits, so as soon as it reaches a condition that is `true`, it stops checking other conditions and returns `true`.

The `|` operator does *not* short-circuit, so it *would* evaluate every operand before returning a value.

Same goes for `&&` and `&` but with `false`. As soon as a false condition is reached, the `&&` operator returns false.

So your two methods are functionally identical. Use whichever one you think is the cleanest, easiest to infer intent, etc.

> Or does the compiler optimize the code to work most efficient no matter how the source is written?

Well, the optimizer can make changes to code for efficiency, but it cannot change the functional behavior, meaning it won't change the *order* of the operations.  Imagine you had something like:

```
if ((x == 0) || (y/x > 1))
```

this is a common way to prevent divide-by-zero errors. If the compiler could rearrange the operands, then it could introduce divide-by-zero errors.

Comment: For completness: there are also the operator `|` and `&` which do not shortcut. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators)

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of preference really, as both will result in the same overall performance.  Both are equivalent to each other.  By default, C# uses short-circuit evaluation, meaning the `if` statement will stop as soon as it finds an expression that evaluates to `true`.  Most of the time, I've seen it written as a single `if` statement, but separate checks can be easier for debugging if you want to put a breakpoint on one of the specific conditions.

Also of note, although `if (myBool == true)` will work, you don't have to explicitly equate it to true.  The `if` statement just has to evaluate to `true`, so you can write it as `if (myBool)`.  Again it's personal preference, but it's shorter and can make it easier to read.

Lastly, you might consider using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, which is just like `string.IsNullOrEmpty` but also checks if the string only contains spaces, tabs, etc., with no content.